# Can the Walnut Street Prison be accessed?

Tags: usa, sightseeing, pennsylvania

In Foucault's *Discipline and Punish*, we see the Walnut Street Prison of Philadelphia mentioned: it was used in the 19th century and apparently is now defunct. I'm curious as to whether the building remains, and if so, if it is open to the public. Wikipedia gives me a street sign acknowledging the former existence of a prison in the area, but both the article and my web searches haven't given me much else.

I realize that there is the Eastern State Penitentiary in the same city, and that that is open to the public, but I'm curious about the Walnut Street building for the same reasons anime and manga fans (at least in Japan) apparently travel to areas featured in shows they follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [one of the sources for that article](http://law.jrank.org/pages/11192/Walnut-Street-Prison.html),

> it was closed in 1835. Later it was razed, and a library now stands on the site.